# If I wanted to develop algorithms for a purely RISC machine, what should my development environment be?

Tags: ide, cpu-architecture

Short of buying a SPARC processor, what emulators are there? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pickup a second hand Power Mac G5 and you can run a fairly recent version of a mainstream OS (ie. OS X 10.5.8) and a modern development environment (Xcode 3.1.4).
You get a pretty fast, modern RISC machine running an OS that is still highly used (for the time being, I admit.)
You could also install Linux onto it if that would be better for your needs.

Probably a lot easier to find and cheaper than a SPARC machine.

Answer (score 1):

You could also install the SPIM emulator for MIPS

Answer (score 0):

On revisiting this, it's worth noting that nearly all modern smartphones run on ARM processors, which is short for 'Acorn **RISC** Machine'. So, an easy answer is 'Android Studio' or anything else targeting phone applications.

Similarly, there's a plethora of simple development boards available inexpensively, such as the BeagleBone Black and the Raspberry Pi, that also carry ARM processors.